# How do I schedule a batch update to a collection in my Firebase Firestore database using Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to JS and Cloud Functions and I would like to perform an update to a collection in my Firestore database every day at midnight. I have a collection `appointmentTimes` with a boolean field `available` and I want to reset this to `true` every day at midnight. So far I've tried using the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.resetAppointmentTimes = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    const appointmentTimesCollectionRef = db.database().collection('appointmentTimes');
    appointmentTimesCollectionRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            return null;
        } else {
            let batch = db.database().batch();
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                batch.update(doc.ref, { available: true });
            });
            return batch.commit();
        }
    }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
})
```

Thank you for any input/suggestions!

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: How do you declare `db`? And what is `db.database()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what is `db.database()`. You should use the Admin SDK and call [`admin.firestore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) to get a Firebase App instance. also, you need to return the Promises chain (watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ for more details).

The following should do the trick:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.resetAppointmentTimes = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    const appointmentTimesCollectionRef = db.collection('appointmentTimes');
    return appointmentTimesCollectionRef.get()  // See the return here
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            return null;
        } else {
            let batch = db.batch();
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                batch.update(doc.ref, { available: true });
            });
            return batch.commit();
        }
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        console.log(error); 
        return null;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) like a cron file

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 0 * * *', function(){
    const appointmentTimesCollectionRef = db.database().collection('appointmentTimes');
appointmentTimesCollectionRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        return null;
    } else {
        let batch = db.database().batch();
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            batch.update(doc.ref, { available: true });
        });
        return batch.commit();
    }
}).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
});
```

Comment: That won't work in Cloud Functions because server instances are not guaranteed to stay up for any amount of time.  They come and go with load on the function.